# How do you style contentEditable in Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, contenteditable

I have the following:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Item 2</div>
```

In webkit I can easily style this with css. Firefox is ignoring the css, and making the contenteditable div white and resizable.

How can I modify the css for contentEditable in Firefox. I want the background to be transparent and to disable resizing, and the resizing handle bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You can match the div with this code

```
div[contenteditable=true] {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* transparent bg */
   resize:none; /* disable resizing */
}
```

Comment: in firefox 7 can I style as I want but I dont know how to remove red underline on wrong words.

Comment: Attribute selectors are defined in CSS2, so it should work. What version of Firefox do you have?

Comment: Still no luck, I even tried: div[contenteditable=true]:focus --- as it only occurs when I click in

Comment: When I click in, I see _moz_resizing="true" on the div. that's the problem. How do i get rid of that?

Answer (score 6):

```
div[contenteditable="true"] {
    /* your style here */
}
```

simone's answer was mostly correct except **there needs to be quotes around "true" in [contenteditable="true"]**

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that if you use position:absolute FF auto adds resizers and a grab handler and sets the background to white. You can't override these seetings, well only resizers. Another -1 for FF.

Comment: big -1 for FF, so... any solution so far? I've tried with jQuery: `$('#target').removeAttr('_moz_abspos').removeAttr('_moz_resizing')` But then `#target` is not editable.

Answer (score 0):

```
div[contenteditable] {
   background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When overriding styles for a contentEditable panel, the css selector I found that firefox was adding a css-selectable "focus-ring" to my root contentEditable node

```
:-moz-focusring:not(input):not(button):not(select):not(textarea):not(iframe):not(frame):not(body):not(html) { outline: 1px dotted;}
```

Try variants of:

```
-moz-focusring or -moz-focusring[contentEditable='true']
```

You may want the aforementioned styles:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
resize:none;
```

But, you may need to firebug lookup the -moz specific resize parameter to disable.

For cross-browser stylesheet tests, just browse to this test data url:

```
data:text/html,<div style='position:absolute;left:100;top:50;width:200;height:300;background-color:rgb(50,50,80)'><div contenteditable>Test<br/>Test </div></div> <style contenteditable>head, title, style {display: block;} :-moz-focusring{background: transparent}</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

A transparent background gif or png should do the trick